# CSS isn't connecting to HTML

Tags: html, css

Sorry for bothering with basics again... 
Really basic problem on webdev, but i'm new and still struggling with the basics so...

Why aren't my css changes applying to html?

The changes to html i made in css aren't applying to the text. I'm not sure why.
The name of the css document is stylesheet.css. 
It used to work before i added the  and cursive for #Art was the only thing is css.
I wrote the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         SanRuza 
      </TITLE>
    <link rel="style" type="text/css" href="style.css">

   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <h1>SanRuza</h1>
   <ul>
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
   <p><div id="Art">"Do something instead of killing time, because time is killing you."</div></b>Paulo Coehlo</p> 
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and i wrote the css:

```
body
{
background-color:gray;
}
h1 {
font-family:Georgia;
font-size:30px;
}
p {
position:relative;
left:150px;
}
#Art {
font-style:italic
}
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li
{
text-decoration:none;
display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Css wise there is nothing wrong. But you named your CSS file wrong in your HTML opening. You named it in document style.css while you said it's stylesheet.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using HTML5. so you no need to define `type` value of `type=text/css` anymore..

your CSS will work if you use only below code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Also noting one thing in your code you didn't close `<!DOCTYPE html`

close it  also.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Yes it seems i forgot to close <!DOCTYPE hmtl> Thank you

Comment: I guess you should close this question by hitting the green check mark button.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

put stylesheet in the rel="" not style ;)
also your link to the css has the wrong name.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

And As you mentioned change `style.css` to `stylesheet.css`

Answer (score 0):

You need to Give like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

Click this link [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a6FSe/)

**Html Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         SanRuza 
      </TITLE>
    <link rel="style" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<style>
body
{
background-color:gray;
}
h1 {
font-family:Georgia;
font-size:30px;
}
p {
position:relative;
left:150px;
}
#Art {
font-style:italic
}
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li
{
text-decoration:none;
display:inline;
}
</style>
   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <h1>SanRuza</h1>
   <ul>
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
   <p><div id="Art">"Do something instead of killing time, because time is killing you."</div></b>Paulo Coehlo</p> 
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes here:

- You've mentioned the filename stylesheet.css but given the link as style.css
- You've given the rel="" wrong

The final code should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

(Assuming its in the same folder)

Answer (score 0):

1. You mentioned that the name of the stylesheet file is stylesheet.css, but what you wrote in HTML is style.css !
2. The value of rel attribute of link tag isn't 'style'. It should be 'stylesheet'.
3. You missed the end angle bracket...

So, you should write your code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         SanRuza 
       </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
       <h1>SanRuza</h1>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
           <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
           <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
       </ul>
       <p><div id="Art">"Do something instead of killing time, because time is killing                you."</div></b>Paulo Coehlo</p> 
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```